# java проверка нажата ли клавиша мыши в браузере или любом другом приложении

Tags: java

хочу написать авто кликкер включающийся если нажаты обе клавиши мыши, как это сделать? гуглил, никакой информации на эту тему не нашёл,только сдесь ровно один подобный вопрос человек задава, И НА НЕГО НЕ ДАЛИ АДЕКВАТНОГО ОТВЕТА!! мне нужно чтобы я мог запустить код на компе, и по нажатию нужных клавишь он начинал закликивать с определённой скоростью.

Comment: Какая ОС? Какая Java?

Comment: убунта, джава вроде 8.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобных задач лучше воспользоваться другим языком (например `С++`, `Delphi` в случае с Windows и тд.) так как `Java` не предназначена для низкоуровневого общения с ОС, потому что код выполняется на `JVM` а не операционной системой напрямую

Comment: у меня линукс, и ни с++ ни тем более Delphi я абсолютно не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Мне немного не понятно хотите ли Вы сделать кликер который будет работать в любом окне системы, или только в фрейме джавы.

Если первое - не уверен что такое возможно, можете конечно поэкспериментировать.

Если второе - в пакете `java.awt.*` есть класс `Robot` у которого есть метод `mousePress`, который воспроизводит клик мыши.

```
public static void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x, y);    
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}
```

Хендлер для кликов мышки можно добавить примерно так:

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       frame.cards1();
    }
  });
```

Comment: в любом приложении кроме джавовых окон. мне нужно не нажать на кнопку мыши, это  как раз работает в любом приложении, а проверить нажата ли.

Comment: на питон такое сделать точно можно, но там 5 кликов в секунду получится. мне надо минимум 15.